# QRegExp Extract Two Numbers

Tags: regex, qt

All I am trying to extract two numbers from a user string.  I have the regexp working, but the second number capture is not being greedy enough!  I can't figure out how to reformat this to my needs, I am submitting my reg exp any advice would be great!

```
QRegExp valid_input(".*(-?\\d*\\.?\\d+)[\\s,]+(-?\\d*.?\\d+)[^\d]*");
valid_input.setMinimal(true);

if(valid_input.indexIn(value.toString()) == -1)
    return false;

QPointF new_point(valid_input.cap(1).toDouble(), valid_input.cap(2).toDouble());
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**Example input:** `156, 264`

**Expected Output:** `156` and `264`

**My Output:** `156` and `2`

---

**Example input:** `156.2 264.52`

**Expected Output:** `156.2` and `264.52`

**My Output:** `156` and `2`

---

**Example input:** `156.2 264.52)`

**Expected Output:** `156.2` and `264.52`

**My Output:** `156` and `2`

Comment: Would help if you'd give some example data along with your expected capture output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex works fine with your examples. Simply do not enable minimal matching and you will get the expected results.

Comment: Okay... that's a little embarrassing

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

- AFAICS from the [manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html) you can remove the leading ".*" and trailing "[^\d]*"
- `setMinimal(true)` talks about setting the regexp being *not* greedy.

Otherwise (for lack of example data) your regexp looks fine.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html shows

> [-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+

which is basically your regexp, with an additional optional plus sign.

An alternative to that, could be to split the regexp into multiple simpler parts:

> ([-+]?\.\d+|[-+]?\d+\.\d*|[-+]?\d+)

Comment: So my problem is the second number.  If I write `156, 435` I'll get back `156` and `4`